# How can I print grep results using curl in a shell script?

Tags: shell, grep, curl

How can I print grep results in a shell script?
This is my code:

```
#url is https://batteryzone.pk/assets/kcfinder/browse.php
read -p "Url: " url
response=$(curl -Lsk $url | grep uploadURL)
if [[ $response =~ uploadURL ]]; then
echo "$url$response"
fi
#and I want the result is $url/uploadfiles/kcfinder
```

The is the result of `curl -Lsk https://batteryzone.pk/assets/kcfinder/browse.php | grep uploadURL`:

```
$ curl -Lsk https://batteryzone.pk/assets/kcfinder/browse.php | grep uploadURL
_.uploadURL = "/assets/kcfinder/upload";
_.thumbsURL = _.uploadURL + "/.thumbs";
```

I want `"$url$response"` to be `$url/uploadfiles/kcfinder`

Comment: I tried to clarify based on the little information you had, but I am not sure this makes sense. Where does the `/uploadfiles/kcfinder` come from? That isn't in the page you are downloading. Is that really the output you want? How can we know this? Should we look for the first occurrence of `uploadURL` and then for whatever is after `/assets/`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Assuming that OP will EDIT to clarify the Question, I wanted to make some comments: (1) OP could "grep -v +" to exclude the second line in $response or the curl output. (2) OP will have to split $res on "/" to generate a list of "words" and remove unwanted elements in this list and insert the replacement string and join back to get "$url$response" (3) Might be Possible to use regex substitutions but this requires clarity on the requirements (4) Perl might be better suited.